# Firefox evaluation of javascript in href of anchor inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

i am trying to evaluate some javascript after the click of a button in an iframe. The button is a link and the javascript is evaluated in the href of that link. It is not my choice to evaluate js in the href but i dont have access to any other attribute because it is an SSRS report.
It seems however that no environment variables are defined in the scope of the iframe button, no `console` no `document`not even `self`.
When i open the iframe report directly and not inside an iframe the scope of the button js includes all the important environment variables.
I am attaching the code of the button.

```
<a tabindex="1" href="javascript:eval%20(%20%20%20%20%20unescape%20%20%20%20%20('self')%20)" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_top"><img onload="this.fitproportional=true;this.pv=0;this.ph=0;" src="/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=cgj2rc55ffw43k45lk0yk055&amp;Culture=2057&amp;CultureOverrides=False&amp;UICulture=9&amp;UICultureOverrides=False&amp;ReportStack=1&amp;ControlID=faa6cce17cd640bf8ebe1f6af602c84b&amp;OpType=ReportImage&amp;IterationId=62c2cb36498248bf8b8b9e784a09d4b8&amp;StreamID=68b4d5bd-b6bf-4d8a-8ad4-b254b9e67c56" border="0" height="35" width="93"></a>
```

Remember that is within an iframe, and the problem only occurs then. The above generates a

```
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You get this behavior if:

1. You're using an old and unsupported version of Firefox (needs to be 32 or older).
2. The subframe your `<a>` tag is in is not same-origin with the top window.

In that situation, since the link is targeting `_top`, the script can't just run in that toplevel window (that would be a same-origin policy violation).  So instead it gets run in a sandbox which has no DOM objects of any sort but has the standard JavaScript objects (`Array`, `Object`, and so forth).

In newer Firefox versions, the script doesn't run at all in this situation, so you won't get an uncaught exception, but it won't do anything either.